# Wordpress critical error (tried plugin + debug!)

Tags: fatal-error

Ever since updating WP to the latest version, the admin panel stopped working. Now, every time attempting to access wp admin just shows this error: **There has been a critical error on this website**. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

There is no email from them.
There is no backup (the hosts, on this occasion, don't have one)

Tried:

1. Renamed plugin folder - didn’t do anything
2. Activated debug mode by editing wp-config file (“WP_DEBUG” true) - didn’t do anything, still showing the same error message

Any advice for fixing this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Add `define('WP_DEBUG', true); define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` in `wp-config.php`, try to open admin panel and then check if there are any messages in the `wp-content/debug.log` file.

Comment: Already tried (see my OP).

Comment: nmr’s point was that a more detailed error will be written to a log file somewhere, either in wp-content or your server or PHP error logs. You need to find that.

Answer (score 0):

- Log in to your hosting.
- Into phpmyadmin
- Select a website database
- Navigate to the wp_options table and open it up.
- Press Ctrl F then find the keyword: active_plugins
- In the options value field of the line active_plugins change to:
- a:0:{}
- Then F5 wp-admin and login.
- Activate each plugin one by one to determine which plugin is causing the error

Comment: That's good advice in general but OP said they've already tried renaming the plugin folder (which would achieve the same thing) and it didn't fix it.

Comment: Exactly. Plugins are not the issue here.

Comment: I am very sorry that the plugin is not your problem.
If the problem is not caused by a plugin you can exclude the theme and php version you are using
You activate the default theme and if the website is still working properly proving your theme has a problem, you need to contact the theme's author to get the upgrade.
If the theme is not your problem then upgrade your php version to 7.4